color of title of lists
How to colorate the title of
List of figures
List of tables
List of graphes
With a defrent colors as Image below

Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

These titles are usually not numbered chapters (\chapter*{…}) or sections (\section*{…}). So they can be configured like those headings, depending on the used class either with features of the class or wit extra packages like titlesec. So an answer depends a lot on the used class and already used packages for headings. Also packages for configurations of ToCs can influence an answer. Therefore we need additional information. See the link in the first comment for the best way to provide this required information.

There are many ways available to meet the requirement, but you have to provide the code what you tried so far, i.e., provide code from \documentclass to \end{document}
